# How to return immediately from forked child process in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, process, execv

I am not familar with linux C development.

my code:

```
....

if((pid=fork())==0){
  //child process
  //start a process, may be need to change execv to other call
  execv (workdir , args);
}else if (pid<0){
  ...
}else{
  ...
}
```

What I want to do is to return immediately from started new process in child process.

Because in the currrent program, `execv (workdir , args);` will not return.  (I need to start a long running process).

What I want to do is start this long run process and return immediately in my C code, so that my C program can exit.

How can I do this?
Maybe make my started new child process a daemon, how to do it by api call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
close(0); open("/dev/null", 0);
close(1);

if(open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY) < 0) {
    perror("/dev/null");
    exit(1);
}

switch(pid = fork()) {
    case -1:
        perror(argv[0]);
        exit(1);
        break;
    case 0:
        fflush(stdout);
        close(2); dup(1);
        setpgrp();
        setsid();
        execv(argv[0], argv);
        execvp(argv[0], argv);
        perror(argv[0]);
        _exit(1);
        break;
    default:
        exit(0);
        break;
}
```

Will fork and detach a process, and exit. It "daemonizes" the program.

Comment: it there any easy way? In shell . when i start a program, for example. firefox. i type "firefox".  if i want to make it run in background , i type "firefox &".  is there similar way in c code?

Comment: Why not just provide a startup script written in bash? It's quite common on linux.

Comment: it's complicated....  we are in a big program. this program is one fo the c called from java. using jni.  and  i am starting firefox .   the firefox is alreday a shell:(  not in bash, because i need to do many other things in c

Comment: can anyone help to explain this :      setpgrp();
        setsid();
        execv(argv[0], argv);
        execvp(argv[0], argv);

Comment: understand each after check man page, but still can't understand why these combination makes a daemon process. :(

Comment: @BenXu I suggest you read Steven's books on advanced Unix programming. It will help a lot.